# Is there a limit to how many concurrent or total retrievals you can make with Platform Cache?

Tags: apex, limits, platform-cache, concurrency

The [features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_features.htm) documentation mentions that the Platform Cache API is what allows you to store and retrieve data that's tied to a Salesforce session or shared across your org. Seeing "API" brings the question of: are there any limits to the # of calls in regards to retrieving/storing platform cache?

Taking a look at the [considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limitations.htm) and [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm) docs, I see no mention to any limit on how often you can store or retrieve. It does mention the following:

> Org cache supports concurrent reads and writes across **multiple** simultaneous Apex transactions.

I might be reading too much into the specific usage of "multiple", but is there any limit here that isn't explicitly mentioned in the docs in terms of:

1. Max # of concurrent reads
2. Total # of retrievals

Comment: No cache-specific concurrency limit, afaik. We use the cache quite a bit, haven't seen a concurrency issue yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform Cache is a Redis store(key-value pairs) and there are no concurrent limits on it simply because salesforce allows the data to be overwritten!

Worst case there will be cache miss so one should have code to rebuild the cache data by handling cache miss scenario!